# duplicate events action in django admin

Tags: python, django, backend

I have a duplicate records function in my django admin.py, and in someway it works, but the weird things is that i have must duplicate this function outside and inside the modelAdmin...

```
def duplicate_event(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    for object in queryset:
        object.id = None
        object.save()
    duplicate_event.short_description = "Duplicate selected record"

class ProductAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Product
    inlines = [CompositionAssociactionAdmin]
    list_display = ("image_img", "code", "name", "price", "discount", "price_offer", "prompt_delivery", "delivery", "promo", "active")
    list_editable = ('active',)
    fields = (
                ("name", "code"), 
                ("price", "discount", "price_offer"),
                ("color", "material"),
                ("scarpemisura", "cintureLunghezza"),
                "size",
                ("width", "lenght", "depth", "height"),
                "volume",
                "descrizione", "album",
                "image", "slider", "thumb", "thumbdue", "croplibero",
                ("prompt_delivery", "delivery"),
                ("slide", "promo"),
                "tags", "active", "pub_date"
            )
    def duplicate_event(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
        for object in queryset:
            object.id = None
            object.save()
        duplicate_event.short_description = "Duplica Record Selezionati"

    actions = ['duplicate_event']
```

before I has try simply so:

```
def duplicate_event(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    for object in queryset:
        object.id = None
        object.save()
    duplicate_event.short_description = "Duplicate selected record"

class ProductAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Product
    inlines = [CompositionAssociactionAdmin]
    list_display = ("image_img", "code", "name", "price", "discount",  "price_offer", "prompt_delivery", "delivery", "promo", "active")
    list_editable = ('active',)
    fields = (
                ("name", "code"), 
                ("price", "discount", "price_offer"),
                ("color", "material"),
                ("scarpemisura", "cintureLunghezza"),
                "size",
                ("width", "lenght", "depth", "height"),
                "volume",
                "descrizione", "album",
                "image", "slider", "thumb", "thumbdue", "croplibero",
                ("prompt_delivery", "delivery"),
                ("slide", "promo"),
                "tags", "active", "pub_date"
            )

    actions = ['duplicate_event']
```

but I get no action.

So I've tried in this other way:

```
class ProductAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Product
    inlines = [CompositionAssociactionAdmin]
    list_display = ("image_img", "code", "name", "price", "discount", "price_offer", "prompt_delivery", "delivery", "promo", "active")
    list_editable = ('active',)
    fields = (
                ("name", "code"), 
                ("price", "discount", "price_offer"),
                ("color", "material"),
                ("scarpemisura", "cintureLunghezza"),
                "size",
                ("width", "lenght", "depth", "height"),
                "volume",
                "descrizione", "album",
                "image", "slider", "thumb", "thumbdue", "croplibero",
                ("prompt_delivery", "delivery"),
                ("slide", "promo"),
                "tags", "active", "pub_date"
            )

    def duplicate_event(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
        for object in queryset:
            object.id = None
            object.save()
        duplicate_event.short_description = "Duplica Record Selezionati"

    actions = ['duplicate_event']
```

and I get this error:
**global name 'duplicate_event' is not defined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation level is wrong, it should be:

```
class ProductAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    def duplicate_event(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
        for object in queryset:
            object.id = None
            object.save()
    duplicate_event.short_description = "Duplica Record Selezionati"
```

The last line, which assigns `duplicate_event.short_description`, should be part of the class body, not part of the method body. The global function is unnecessary.